# How do I make the perforce command line view the same as the P4Win view

Tags: perforce

I've written some python tools which work with the p4 command line to work on files I have opened in P4Win. However it seems like the p4 view can become different to the P4Win view. I'm not quite sure how to make them the same.

Comment: I haven't used p4win myself (only command line p4) but if you describe what it looks like or perhaps attach a screenshot, I might be able to help you out.

Comment: If you could attach more details about how you invoke p4 command, it will be easier to help you out. For me right now it seems that in P4Win you open files from your workspace, and from p4 you open files from your depot (repository) or other way round.

Comment: I just do 'p4 opened' and the list of files is different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe by 'view' you mean client workspace? In which case the workspace selected by P4Win and p4 command-line are independent.

You need to use `p4 set` to select the same workspace for command-line as you've selected for P4Win.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that's what I needed, to use p4 set to make the port the same, as I switched servers in p4win and expected it to magically do the same at the command line. 

   p4 set P4PORT=yourserver:yourport